# Remove [database] from the example tags when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, asking-questions

When asking a question there are three suggested tags, put there as an example of what one can use:

> [image]

[java](/questions/tagged/java) and [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) work as good examples of the sort of tags people should be using and the characters it's possible to use in a tag.

[database](/questions/tagged/database), however, does not. I'm not trying to get into an argument about how useful [database](/questions/tagged/database) is; but, I *do* think it should be removed from this list as it might encourage poor tagging.

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql) is one of the most commonly used tags on Stack Overflow but unlike [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) it normally requires extra clarification. The number of questions that get posted with only the tags [database](/questions/tagged/database) and/or [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) is really frustrating; forcing someone to ask what RDBMS the questioner is using.

Can the wording be changed to something like the following?

> at least one tag such as (java, asp.net-mvc or sql and sql-server), max 5 tags

Comment: Perhaps you could also add some examples of questions you have seen where only [database] is tagged. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786296/how-can-i-do-database-about-e-r) a good example.

Comment: I would love to @asad but my internet has just crapped out on me :(. I can assure you that if the question was at all good the tags will now have been changed which means it's a difficult task... Those that are left will normally be design questions or not worth saving.

Comment: Okay, not tagged just [database] but it's a completely pointless tag on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786979/form-posts-unwanted-commas-to-database

Comment: sql does not always need further information many queries can be written standard sql

Comment: Of course @Mark, but as not every RDBMS implements the ANSI standard and those that do implement it differently a questioner will usually be able to get a better answer if they add the RDBMS in.

Comment: Isn't that list dynamically created from the most popular tags on the site?

Comment: I don't think so @ÄlËverett, no guarantees of course. It's always been the same as far as I remember. Either way there are better tags that could be used. Though now I look again [regex] is there. An equally bad tag...

Comment: The point is that standard sql is supported by most rdbms and so tagging with just this makes the question and answer relevant to many more people than just using the specific one